# Revision history depending on the site, not the entry

Tags: content, draft, revisions

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/8912

I have a site with a large number of subsites, so it would be very useful for content editors to save revisions/drafts for each site instead of entry.

So far it looks like a craft limitation, but maybe there is a plugin or some kind of custom solution for this case?

Does anybody occur the same issue?

Comment: What‘s the propagation setting for the section you‘re having the problem with?

Comment: This is about the whole site, not the single section. For example,I have a multisite section with 1 non-translatable field and when I select revision/draft it applies to the current selected entry but not the one it was originally created in.

Comment: yes, I know, but I would still be interested in the propagation setting of one of your affected sections...

Comment: Propagate to each site.